# How do I get the "key" of an array item in OPENJSON, when using WITH?

Tags: json, sql-server, open-json, json-value

I want to parse a json-array in my sql-server. I would like to use `OPENJSON` with `WITH` to parse specific values into columns. How can I get the index of each array item?

I know, that this works fine with `JSON_VALUE` and without `WITH`:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"name":"Alpha"},{"name":"Bravo"},{"name":"Charlie"}]'

SELECT [key], JSON_VALUE(value, '$.name')
FROM OPENJSON(@json)

--  key | value
----------------------------------
--    0 | Alpha
--    1 | Bravo
--    2 | Charlie
```

But when I add `WITH` I seem to not have access to `key` anymore.

```
SELECT [key], name
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
  [key] INT, -- does not work
  name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

--  key | name
----------------------------------
-- NULL | Alpha
-- NULL | Bravo
-- NULL | Charlie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON()` with the default schema to get the key of each array item (as your first attempt). A note in the documentation [explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value):

> Note: The Key, Value, and Type columns are returned only when you use
> OPENJSON with the default schema and are not available with an
> explicit schema.

The following statement is just another option to get the keys and parse the JSON using an explicit schema:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"name":"Alpha"},{"name":"Bravo"},{"name":"Charlie"}]';

SELECT j1.[key], j2.* 
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j1.[value]) WITH (name nvarchar(max)) j2
```

Result:

```
key name
---------
0   Alpha
1   Bravo
2   Charlie
```